# Using QList as the input for QwtPlotCurves setSamples

Tags: qt, qwt, qlist

I have two QList (XList, YList) which saves the dynamic data. I want to use these as the input of the QwtPlotCurves by setSamples. After I check the documentation:

```
void    setSamples (const double *xData, const double *yData, int size)
void    setSamples (const QVector< double > &xData, const QVector< double > &yData)
void    setSamples (const QVector< QPointF > &)
```

It seems do not support QList. Is there workaround to this or do I have to overload it?

Julio

Answer (score 1):

There is method in QList that returns a const QVector.

So:

```
setSamples( XList.toVector(), YList.toVector()  )
```

Check [QVector QList::toVector () const](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlist.html#toVector)

Comment: So this has to be done every time I update the plot? OK, I'll check the efficiency.